# Print all combinations of a number as a sum of candidate numbers

Tags: algorithm

Does anyone have a solution to the following question? It seems like a classic problem, but I haven't found any good answers online yet.

> Given a target number, and a series of candidate numbers, print out all combinations, so that the sum of candidate numbers equals to the target.
>
> Here order is not important, so don’t print the duplicated combination.
>
> e.g. target is 7, candidate is 2,3,6,7
> output should be 7 and 3+2+2 (but not print 2+3+2, 2+2+3)

Comment: This is the subset sum problem, it's a classic dynamic programming problem. You can Google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to print all the combinations, you can employ a general complete search program using recursion. For example, [this code](http://ideone.com/6PinIW) solves the problem and prints all such combinations.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;

class Solution{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)throws java.lang.Exception{
        new Solution().run();
    }

    int N = 7;
    int[] arr = {2, 3, 6, 7};
    int[] vals = new int[N];;

    void run(){
        printCombinations(N, 0, 0);
    }

    // from : consider numbers in arr from index "from"
    // index: add new number in array vals at index "index"
    void printCombinations(int target, int from, int index){
        if(target==0){
            for(int i=0; i<index; i++){
                System.out.print(vals[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }else if(target<0 || from>=arr.length){
            return;
        }else{
            vals[index] = arr[from];
            // take arr[from] in set
            printCombinations(target-arr[from], from, index+1);

            // dont take arr[from] in set
            printCombinations(target, from+1, index);
        }
    }
}
```

The only pre condition to using the function printCombinations is that the array arr must not contain duplicates. And if it contains duplicates, we can easily remove them using a Set.

In the code N is required target. And arr is the set of candidate numbers.
for N=7 and arr[] = {2, 3, 6, 7} the code prints:

```
2 2 3 
7
```

Comment: the best answer to this question by far.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code which uses backtracking.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    int[] arr = {2,3,6,7};
    int target = 9; 

    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    printCombinations(result, arr, target, 0);
}

private static void printCombinations(ArrayList<Integer> result, int[] arr, int target, int counter) {

    if(target == 0) {
        System.out.println(result);
        return;
    }

    if(target < 0 || counter>=arr.length) {
        return;
    }

    result.add(arr[counter]);
    printCombinations(result, arr, target-arr[counter], counter);

    result.remove(result.indexOf(arr[counter]));
    printCombinations(result, arr, target, counter+1);
}
```

If the candidate number has to be used only once, then just change the first recursive call and use 'counter+1' instead of  'counter'.

```
private static void printCombinations(ArrayList<Integer> result, int[] arr, int target, int counter) {

    if(target == 0) {
        System.out.println(result);
        return;
    }

    if(target < 0 || counter>=arr.length) {
        return;
    }

    result.add(arr[counter]);
    printCombinations(result, arr, target-arr[counter], counter+1);

    result.remove(result.indexOf(arr[counter]));
    printCombinations(result, arr, target, counter+1);


}
```